# Directly invoke a servlet without a URL?

Tags: java, servlets

I had two java web apps with servlets that communicated with each other using absolute URLs.  I did this because they wouldn't always be running on the same server and even when they were it still worked fine.

However, I've now changed the code so there is only a single web app and the first app (A) now uses the second app (B) more as a library.  So, I'd like to be able to make calls on the second app directly without having to know the full URL.

Ideally, the servlets in B would be pure controllers, but unfortunately they are not and the logic is wrapped up in the request and the response and not easily decoupled.

The only option I've seen is to use a RequestDispatcher.  However, when getting a dispatcher using the context:

```
context.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet/mapping");
```

To make the call I'd then need to synthesize a request and response object and I don't know how to do this.  I've looked into wrappers but they need to start from something yet I don't have a starting point.  I could create my own wrapper to handle the query parameters, but again, I don't have a request to start from.

Or is there a simpler solution that I'm missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just turn all your request.getParameter() type calls into regular passing of variables to a function.  Assuming your servlet writes out text and not binary, turn all your out.prints into concatenations to a string you return at the end of the servlet. Or pass in an outputstream rather than response object, and instead of calling the servlet response.getouputstream use the outputstream passed in.  Then you can make your servlet just a regular class that takes some parameters and returns a string or prints to an outputstream that you passed in.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I realize this is the best solution, but as I said I have things a bit more intertwined than I'd like to admit, and before I fixed things I wanted to know all of my alternatives.  If the RequestDispatcher is the only option then I'll likely have to go with your (i.e., the obvious) solution.  Thanks again!